# Is there some way to modify the method name in grpc C++?

Tags: grpc

I use grpc cpp, and want to modify the method name in the client, example: path+method, but the ClientInterceptor could not modify method? How can I do

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify the method name by the interceptor. I guess you considered using pre-send initial metadata but it doesn't allow to change the method name. But the intercept allows you to hijack the call, send a new rpc, and return the result from this new rpc as an original result to achieve what you want to do.